# Wordpress : Too Many Images Versions

Tags: wordpress, image

I have a small problem which is probably at noob level.

I haven't noticed how extremely one of my wordpress sites is cluttering up my webserver.

It's an eCommerce site and for every image uploaded. It creates 28 versions of them. So with over 800 items there is a considerable number.

I have tried to output all preview templates via a function.

```
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

// List of standard image sizes
$sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

// List of registered image sizes
$registered_sizes = array_merge( $sizes, array_keys( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $registered_sizes );
echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

> [0] => thumbnail
> [1] => medium
> [2] => medium_large
> [3] => large
> [4] => 1536x1536
> [5] => 2048x2048
> [6] => widget
> [7] => square
> [8] => featured
> [9] => featured_large
> [10] => extra_large
> [11] => portfolio
> [12] => portfolio_small
> [13] => gallery
> [14] => magazine
> [15] => masonry
> [16] => entry_with_sidebar
> [17] => entry_without_sidebar
> [18] => shop_thumbnail
> [19] => shop_catalog
> [20] => shop_single
> [21] => 1536x1536
> [22] => 2048x2048
> [23] => widget
> [24] => square
> [25] => featured
> [26] => featured_large
> [27] => extra_large
> [28] => portfolio
> [29] => portfolio_small
> [30] => gallery
> [31] => magazine
> [32] => masonry
> [33] => entry_with_sidebar
> [34] => entry_without_sidebar
> [35] => shop_thumbnail
> [36] => shop_catalog
> [37] => shop_single

How can I reduce this (also retroactively for the old images)?

[FileZilla Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLH5h.png)

I hope someone can help me to reduce this mountain of images.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your unnecessary image sizes by adding a filter hook.

```
/**
 * Remove additional image sizes.
 */
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'wp98_remove_additional_image_sizes' );
function wp98_remove_additional_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    unset( $sizes['extra_large'] );
    unset( $sizes['my_custom_size'] );
    
    return $sizes;
}
```

Change `'extra_large', 'my_custom_size'` with your image size